# Hive query, efficient non equi join?

Tags: join, hive

I have two tables.

tableOne contains

userid
gameid
starttimestamp
endtimestamp

tableTwo contains

userid
actiontimestamp
someaction

Given the userid and gameid, I want to see how many actions there were in each game id. Given  only equi join is allowed, what's a efficient way to join them together?

Most of my crossjoin and filter attempts ended up mapper and reducer getting stuck at 100%.

Answer (score 1):

You could handle all your "theta join" (non-equijoin) conditions in the WHERE clause.  Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM OrderLineItem li LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductPrice p ON p.ProductID = li.ProductID
WHERE (p.StartDate IS NULL AND p.EndDate IS NULL)
OR li.OrderDate BETWEEN p.StartDate AND p.EndDate;
```

Of course, this example assumes StartDate and EndDate are both non-nullable columns of ProductPrice.

Answer (score 0):

Non equi joins are not available in Hive.

For optimizing equi joins you can try the following.

1.You can implement [Buckets](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/download/attachments/27362054/Hive+Summit+2011-join.pdf?version=1&modificationDate=1309986642000) in Hive.

2.Read this [facebook article](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/join-optimization-in-apache-hive/470667928919)  also.

3.Do you have more than one job ?.if yes ,enable parallel execution in hive.
if your jobs are indepenent they run parallel.

4.If one of the tables is small ,use distributed cache with add file option in hive.